# Prestashop 1.7.8 - Can't create new category since update

Tags: prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.7

I recently upgrade my Prestashop from 1.7.6 to 1.7.8 with module 1-Click Upgrade.

I also upgrade php to the supported version and everything should work perfectly.

But when I try to create a new category from the back-office, I have a Prestashop error saying that I can't.

I emptied cache but nothing change and debug mode display nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to check server errors to find real error message or turn ob PrestaShop debug mode

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you're right. So my issue is from a custom module.